# How to implement converter class in usercontrol

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I want to make a converter class , I implemented it and i want to use it in another xaml class
So i write this code

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PoliceApp"
    xmlns:common="using:PoliceApp.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

        <UserControl.Resources>
            <local:TitleToImgConverter x:Key="BoolOrConverter"/>
        </UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl>
```

It tells me that there is a missing attribute for user control

and my first code was

```
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PoliceApp"
    xmlns:common="using:PoliceApp.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

        <UserControl.Resources>
            <local:TitleToImgConverter x:Key="BoolOrConverter"/>
        </UserControl.Resources>
```

And the error was "The name titletoimgconverter doesnt exist in the namespace using:policeApp"

Answer (score 1):

This is normal (at least, I have never seen it otherwise) when you have just created a new converter and added it as a resource in your XAML code. XAML code often lags behind when something is added to the namespace.

The solution for this is to rebuild your entire project. The XAML should now be able to locate your converter, and the error should disappear.

**Update**
If your converter exists in some folder called `Converter`, you should use your first example, and replace `xmlns:local="using:PoliceApp"` with `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PoliceApp.Converter"`. If it just resides in your main folder, you can leave out the `.Converter`. Note that I've replaced the `using:` with `clr-namespace:`.

Comment: which code is the right one ? the first or the second?